# Error sending password reset email: authInstance._getRecaptchaConfig is not a function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, firebase-authentication, vue-composition-api

I got this error when trying to reset the password in firebase auth.
[image]
Basically, I have seen that this error occurs due to wrong path to firebase auth or firebase version in package.json. But I checked everything, with other firebase functions everything works

```
import {
    getAuth,
    createUserWithEmailAndPassword,
    signInWithEmailAndPassword,
    signOut,
    onAuthStateChanged,
    GoogleAuthProvider,
    signInWithPopup,
    updateProfile,
    updatePhoneNumber,
    sendPasswordResetEmail
} from "firebase/auth"
import {todosRef, todosUser, db, firebaseApp, auth as Auth} from "@/firebase/firestore";
    const reset = async (): Promise<void> => {
        try {

            const user = Auth.currentUser;

            if (user) {
                await sendPasswordResetEmail(user.email)
                    .then((): void => {
                        Swal.fire({
                            title: "Check your email",
                            text: "Password reset email sent successfully.",
                            icon: "success"
                        });
                    })
                    .catch((error: string | any): void => {
                        console.error("Error sending password reset email:", error.message);
                        Swal.fire({
                            title: "Error",
                            text: "Failed to send password reset email.",
                            icon: "error"
                        });
                    });
            } else {
                console.error("User not authenticated");
                await Swal.fire({
                    title: "Error",
                    text: "User not authenticated.",
                    icon: "error"
                });
            }
        } catch (e) {
            console.error("Error:", e);
        }
    };
```